# Using reflect, how do you set the value of a struct field?

Tags: go, reflection, go-reflect

having a rough time working with struct fields using `reflect` package.  in particular, have not figured out how to set the field value.

```
type t struct { fi int; fs string }
var r t = t{ 123, "jblow" }
var i64 int64 = 456
```

1. getting Name of field i - this seems to work

   `var field = reflect.TypeOf(r).Field(i).Name`
2. getting value of field i as a) interface{}, b) int - this seems to work

   `var iface interface{} = reflect.ValueOf(r).Field(i).Interface()`

   `var i int = int(reflect.ValueOf(r).Field(i).Int())`
3. setting value of field i - try one - panic

   `reflect.ValueOf(r).Field(i).SetInt( i64 )`

   *panic*: reflect.Value·SetInt using value obtained using unexported field

   assuming it did not like field names "id" and "name", so renamed to "Id" and "Name"

   a) is this assumption correct?

   b) if correct, thought not necessary since in same file / package
4. setting value of field i - try two (with field names capitalized ) - panic

   `reflect.ValueOf(r).Field(i).SetInt( 465 )`

   `reflect.ValueOf(r).Field(i).SetInt( i64 )`

   *panic*: reflect.Value·SetInt using unaddressable value

---

Instructions below by @peterSO are thorough and high quality

Four. this works:

`reflect.ValueOf(&r).Elem().Field(i).SetInt( i64 )`

he documents as well that the field names must be exportable (begin with capital letter)

Comment: the closest example I could find for someone using `reflect` to set data was http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.go.general/35045, but even there he used `json.Unmarshal` to do the actual dirty work

Comment: (the above comment is obsolete)

Answer (score 209, accepted):

The Go json package marshals and unmarshals JSON from and to Go structures.

Here's a step-by-step example which sets the value of a `struct` field while carefully avoiding errors.

The Go [`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package has a [`CanAddr`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.CanAddr) function.

```
func (v Value) CanAddr() bool
```

> CanAddr returns true if the value's
> address can be obtained with Addr.
> Such values are called addressable. A
> value is addressable if it is an
> element of a slice, an element of an
> addressable array, a field of an
> addressable struct, or the result of
> dereferencing a pointer. If CanAddr
> returns false, calling Addr will
> panic.

The Go [`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package has a [`CanSet`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.CanSet) function, which, if `true`, implies that `CanAddr` is also `true`.

```
func (v Value) CanSet() bool
```

> CanSet returns true if the value of v
> can be changed. A Value can be changed
> only if it is addressable and was not
> obtained by the use of unexported
> struct fields. If CanSet returns
> false, calling Set or any
> type-specific setter (e.g., SetBool,
> SetInt64) will panic.

We need to make sure we can `Set` the `struct` field. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    type t struct {
        N int
    }
    var n = t{42}
    // N at start
    fmt.Println(n.N)
    // pointer to struct - addressable
    ps := reflect.ValueOf(&n)
    // struct
    s := ps.Elem()
    if s.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        // exported field
        f := s.FieldByName("N")
        if f.IsValid() {
            // A Value can be changed only if it is 
            // addressable and was not obtained by 
            // the use of unexported struct fields.
            if f.CanSet() {
                // change value of N
                if f.Kind() == reflect.Int {
                    x := int64(7)
                    if !f.OverflowInt(x) {
                        f.SetInt(x)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // N at end
    fmt.Println(n.N)
}

Output:
42
7
```

If we can be certain that all the error checks are unnecessary, the example simplifies to,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    type t struct {
        N int
    }
    var n = t{42}
    fmt.Println(n.N)
    reflect.ValueOf(&n).Elem().FieldByName("N").SetInt(7)
    fmt.Println(n.N)
}
```

**BTW**, Go is available as [open source code](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/). A good way to learn about reflection is to see how the core Go developers use it. For example, the Go [fmt](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) and [json](http://golang.org/pkg/json/) packages. The package documentation has links to the source code files under the heading Package files.

Comment: Give Up!  somewhere in there is an answer, but four hours of work on the json pkg have not yielded it to me.  re the reflect pkg, pulling info is pretty straightforward, but setting data requires some of black magic for which I would love to see a simple example somewhere!

Comment: Outstanding!  if you're ever in Thailand please let me treat you to a beer or two or three!  thank you very much

Comment: Great practical example, this article completely demystified it for me http://golang.org/doc/articles/laws_of_reflection.html

Comment: Awesome example.Here is playground sample of the same code http://play.golang.org/p/RK8jR_9rPh

Comment: This doesn't set a struct field. This sets a field in a pointer to struct. Obviously, this is not answering the question OP asked.

Comment: omg, why is go so painful to use. Grumble, grumble grumble. Repeat the above for all the different data types and you see what i mean

Comment: Reflect is a terrible thing. Programmer can visit the unexport field just as fmt.Printf can show us the unexport field. Thanks golang team, they won't allow programmers to change the unexport field. Or else something ridiculous will come.

Comment: Supplement: The necessary condition for [CanSet](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.CanSet) to return true is that the attribute of the struct must have an **uppercase prefix**.

Answer (score 22):

This seems to work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo struct {
    Number int
    Text string
}

func main() {
    foo := Foo{123, "Hello"}

    fmt.Println(int(reflect.ValueOf(foo).Field(0).Int()))

    reflect.ValueOf(&foo).Elem().Field(0).SetInt(321)

    fmt.Println(int(reflect.ValueOf(foo).Field(0).Int()))
}
```

Prints:

```
123
321
```

Comment: thanks!  now that I've read peterSO's notes, this makes perfect sense.  I was using foo, not &foo, so could not be changed,  and was unsure what Elem() was about.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a helper function to set values:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

type Apple struct {
    Color     string
    CreatedAt time.Time
}

func SetValue(obj any, field string, value any) {
    ref := reflect.ValueOf(obj)

    // if its a pointer, resolve its value
    if ref.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        ref = reflect.Indirect(ref)
    }

    if ref.Kind() == reflect.Interface {
        ref = ref.Elem()
    }

    // should double check we now have a struct (could still be anything)
    if ref.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        log.Fatal("unexpected type")
    }

    prop := ref.FieldByName(field)
    prop.Set(reflect.ValueOf(value))
}

func main() {
    myStruct := Apple{}
    SetValue(&myStruct, "Color", "red")
    SetValue(&myStruct, "CreatedAt", time.Now())
    fmt.Printf("Result: %+v\n", myStruct)
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/uHoy5n3k1DW