# How to return from function with some error checking in Go

Tags: go

I have several data to load, and If one of them fails, I have to log error and not continue to run the code.
Is this code OK? And how to do that?

```
func (worker *Worker) GetData() error {
  err := worker.LoadModelA()
  if err != nil && worker.LogError()  // LogError alway return true
    return err

  err = worker.LoadModelB()
  if err != nil && worker.LogError()  // LogError alway return true
    return err

  return err
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With error in A (try it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5YnhFN0TMC)), output:

```
LoadModelA
2009/11/10 23:00:00 LogError
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Error LoadModelB
```

With error in B (try it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-vZeZi5Moh)), output:

```
LoadModelA
LoadModelB
2009/11/10 23:00:00 LogError
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Error LoadModelB
```

Without error (try it on[The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/T0It5A5cXS)), output:

```
LoadModelA
LoadModelB
Done.
main Done.
```

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func (worker *Worker) GetData() error {
    if err := worker.LoadModelA(); err != nil {
        worker.LogError()
        return err
    }
    if err := worker.LoadModelB(); err != nil {
        worker.LogError()
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("Done.")
    return nil
}

func main() {
    w := &Worker{}
    err := w.GetData()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("main Done.")
}

type Worker struct{}

func (w *Worker) LoadModelA() error {
    fmt.Println("LoadModelA")
    return nil
    //return fmt.Errorf("Error LoadModelB")
}
func (w *Worker) LoadModelB() error {
    fmt.Println("LoadModelB")
    return nil
    //return fmt.Errorf("Error LoadModelB")
}
func (w *Worker) LogError() error {
    log.Println("LogError")
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I hope this helps. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I think your way is better than mine. Thanks Amd . I just get started golang. Do you know any forum or blog guid new guy like me to get better coding :)

Comment: Yup! Thanks a ton ;)

Comment: @Peter_175 A few good resources: http://reddit.com/r/golang, http://forum.golangbridge.org, and #go-nuts IRC channel (http://irc.lc/freenode/go-nuts)

Answer (score 0):

With a small number of "several" you can simply have

```
func (worker *Worker) GetData() (err error) {
    if err = worker.LoadModelA(); err == nil {
        if err = worker.LoadModelB(); err == nil {
            return
        }
    }
    worker.LogError()
    return
}
```

On large numbers you can [loop through the fields of struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350173/how-do-you-loop-through-the-fields-in-a-golang-struct-to-get-and-set-values-in-a)