# reflect.Value string not changing with SetString()

Tags: go

I'm having a bit of trouble setting a reflect.Value which is a string to something different.

In the follow `GetValue()` return a `reflect.Value`

```golang
val, err := exp.GetFact(t.(*api.Event_Set).Set.Key).GetValue()
if err != nil {
    ref := reflect.Indirect(val)
    ref.SetString(t.(*api.Event_Set).Set.Value)
}
```

Upon hitting SetString it throws a panic:

```sh
panic: reflect: reflect.Value.SetString using unaddressable value
```

I've attempted different syntax ie without an Indirect, with an Elem() etc. How do I correctly change the value of the string?

Comment: What is the type of `val`?

Comment: Oh yeah, I mentioned above GetValue returns reflect.Value. The value contained is a basic string.

Comment: No, we mean what is the value contained in the `val` `reflect.Value`? The error is that you have an unaddressable value, you cannot make that addressable after the fact.

Comment: If it is just `string` and not `*string`, I think that would be the source of your problem.

Comment: I'm going to be honest, I'm not totally sure because it's set by a library and I'm not defining it myself. If it is indeed *string how would I properly address it? Thanks for your help btw. I appreciate it

Comment: Can the reflection library tell me exactly what it is? I tried TypeOf and it's just reporting reflect.Value lol. Sighhhh. Would I have to readdress it based on its type?

Comment: If you provide a reference to the library in question then we can provide a more specific answer (by looking at the source code).  In general, if the value given to the `reflect.Value` was not a pointer to begin with, there's no meaningful way to turn it into a pointer, because all association with the original "real" value has been lost. (also btw try `val.Type().String()`)

Comment: Well this is the method that's creating the value for me inside the library: https://github.com/hyperjumptech/grule-rule-engine/blob/90f4cf9e2ac03e8ceb1286ed85dc8fd47a45620e/ast/DataContext.go#L87 this is confusing to me it's like meta reflection haha

Comment: @ddibiase In that case, it depends on the original call site of `DataContext.Add` where the value in question is added.  If, at that call site, the value added is of type `string` (not `*string`), then no matter what reflection magic you cast, you won't be able to modify this value.  If what you want to do is update the value in the `DataContext.ObjectStore`, perhaps you should just call `DataContext.Add` again to update it. Looking at the code, this will just update the existing association.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought as well but I wasn't sure if there were symptoms of doing that. I also posed the question in their Discussions but didn't grasp the answer totally: https://github.com/hyperjumptech/grule-rule-engine/discussions/188#discussioncomment-652010

Answer (score 1):

I may don't have the complete code, but something like this works:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    s := "test"
    value := reflect.ValueOf(&s)
    ref := reflect.Indirect(value)
    ref.Set(reflect.ValueOf("test1"))
    fmt.Printf(s)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I saw something like this, using code from the last answerer.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    s := "test"
    ref := reflect.ValueOf(&s).Elem()
    ref.Set(reflect.ValueOf("test1"))
    fmt.Printf(s)
}
```

Comment: You can add more information about how this can help. Also, you can explain the differences between the code of the other answer and yours in order to help the community.