# Converting string into field names

Tags: struct, go, maps

I have a structure, where I store all the hours and minutes into mongodb. In this case, when  I get a request to modify the value, I get the hour and minute as string. Is there a way to find the field name from the string that is given as input

You can see it [here](https://play.golang.org/p/g-7MLHc0Io)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Min struct {
    v01 int `bson:"01",json:"01"`
    v02 int `bson:"02",json:"02"`
}

type Hour struct {
    v01 Min `bson:"01",json:"01"`
    v02 Min `bson:"02",json:"02"`
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    var h Hour
    h.v01.v01 = 1
    h.v02.v01 = 2
    fmt.Println(h)
    h.Set("01", "01", 10)
    fmt.Println(h)
}

func (h *Hour) Set(hour string, min string, value int) {
    h.v01.v01 = 10 //Here I have hardcoded it
    // Is there a way to do this from the given input
    // e.g. h.Set("01","01",100)
}
```

If you notice, the input is `"01","01"`. I would like to change this input as `h.v01.v01`. Is it possible in Go?

Note: I am using currently `maps` in this case. I would like to change this into structure access, if possible, so that I can use goroutine to speed up my program. Currently goroutines are not safe for writing into maps.

Comment: Goroutines are not safe for concurrently writing *anything*. Regardless if you have a map or a struct, you need to synchronize access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GoLang: Access struct property by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930910/golang-access-struct-property-by-name)

Answer (score 0):

> Currently goroutines are not safe for writing into maps.

That might need to be revisited with Go 1.9 (Aug. 2017) and the [concurrent map](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#sync-map) present in the [`sync` package](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map)

> The new `Map` type in the `sync` package is a concurrent map with amortized-constant-time loads, stores, and deletes.
>   It is safe for multiple goroutines to call a `Map`'s methods concurrently.

Combine that with [`oleiade/reflections`](https://github.com/oleiade/reflections) that I mentioned, as commented, in "[GoLang: Access struct property by name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25616428/6309)", and you should be able to do both (access property name, and use maps)