# Getting substruct field in Go

Tags: go, struct

I am trying to get fields from a `struct` value using reflection.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Vertex struct {
    X         string
    Y         string
    SubVertex SubVertex
}
type SubVertex struct {
    Z string
}

func get_field(v Vertex, field string) string {
    r := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    f := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName(field)
    return f.String()
}

func main() {
    v := Vertex{"a", "b", SubVertex{"c"}}

    fmt.Println(get_field(v, "X"))
    fmt.Println(get_field(v, "Y"))
    fmt.Println(get_field(v, "Z"))  // Invalid Value
}
```

I get **Invalid Value** in the third case, when I try to get the value of the `Z` field. If `SubVertex` were an anonymous field, this would work, but I need to use a named field.

How do I make this work?

Comment: Works fine in the playground https://play.golang.org/p/fgnOdNRDA0

Comment: Not for me... https://play.golang.org/p/bMCKdzFe0i
A B
<invalid Value>

Comment: I edited the question -- it was confusing originally because working code was presented along with some slightly hard-to-understand changes described in prose that actually represent the problem.

Comment: PS: this appears to be a variant of code that I originally wrote in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930910/golang-access-struct-property-by-name/18931036#18931036 . Some of the things I said there apply here too -- especially about avoiding reflection.

Comment: If you don't embed SubVertex, you're using reflection to find the field Z in a struct that has no field Z (it has a field sub.Z, but not Z).  If you need the sub field, you need to either look for the struct and then the field in that struct, or embed the struct.

Comment: I note also that the `reflect.Indirect` is redundant here -- in the original version of the code the Vertex was passed in via a pointer, but that's not the case here.

Comment: This works, but probably isn't what you want, but may give you an idea. You could maybe detect an invalid value and in that case, go deeper. https://play.golang.org/p/kgEDjYcovo

Comment: yep, this gives me an idea, thnx. Using pointers does not change anything I think. search for "SubVertex.Z" in original version gives <invalid value> too. But now that get_subvertex_field makes it clearer for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you have to use the reflect package in the same manner as you would accessing the values normally. So

```
v.X // a
v.Y // b
v.SubVertex.Z // c
```

becomes

```
r := reflect.ValueOf(v)
x := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName("X")
x.String() // a
...
z := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName("SubVertex").FieldByName("Z")
z.String() // c
```

Note that `FieldByName()` is called on a `Value` and returns a `Value`, so it works much the same as just accessing it regularly. Also note that as per the documentation:

> Indirect returns the value that v points to. If v is a nil pointer, Indirect returns a zero Value. If v is not a pointer, Indirect returns v.

So the call to `Indirect()` would be a No-op, but would protect it from having a meltdown if you decided to give it a pointer in the future.

As for your function, this would work

```
func get_field(v Vertex, field string) string {
    r := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    if field == "Z" {
        f := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName("SubVertex").FieldByName(field)
        return f.String()
    }
    f := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName(field)

    return f.String()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/eZyTl8OSTZ