# value returned by flags into my struct

Tags: go, go-flag

How can I assign the string value returned by flag into my struct?  I have the following code.

```
destDbCfg = &dbhelper.DbConfig {}

destDbCfg.Database = flag.String( "destDBName", "", "Destination DB Database Name")
flag.Parse()
```

Database is a string

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061616/9935654

Answer (score 1):

Use the `*Var` methods to set set values to existing variables from flags, in this case you want [`flag.StringVar`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#StringVar:)

```
destDbCfg = &dbhelper.DbConfig{}

flag.StringVar(&destDbCfg.Database, "destDBName", "", "Destination DB Database Name")
flag.Parse()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!