# How to get property of struct by name?

Tags: go, reflection

I have this struct definition :

```
// Two columns, both strings.
type ExampleStructItem struct {
    Firstname string
    Surname string
}
```

and I have this slice of column names :

```
columns := []string{"Firstname", "Surname"}
```

and I am essentially trying to loop through my slice of column names, and then perform reflection on the corresponding struct to get information about the properties, such as their "Kind" etc.

Comment: You do reflection using the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect) package. From your wording it seems like maybe you're already somewhat familiar with this. Have you tried any implementation? If so, can you post that code & what issues you had with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930910/access-struct-property-by-name.

Comment: @Adrian reflection is a totally new thing to me - I was able to do things like get the kind on a hard coded property of a struct - but I am totally unfamiliar with how I might get it by name like this - I've been unable to even get something to work at all.

Comment: @ThunderCat - Not technically a duplicate - I saw this question before but it doesn't really talk about having a slice of columns to work with, and then trying to work with it to find the properties.

Comment: @MickeyThreeSheds it gives you all the information you need to write your implementation. Just because a question isn't your *exact* scenario with an answer you can copy and paste into your code doesn't mean it isn't a valid duplicate. If you don't know how to loop over a slice, take the Tour of Go.

Comment: @Adrian the poster below understood my question, and gave a working answer. It's pretty different to the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Type.FieldByName()`

```
var ex ExampleStructItem
t := reflect.TypeOf(ex)

for _, name := range columns {

    field, ok := t.FieldByName(name)
    if ok {
        k := field.Type.Kind()
    } else {
        // error handling
    }

}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/U0evr_jCDCq)

Comment: Perfect! I will accept this as the best answer as soon as stack over flow lets me! Thankyou!

Comment: Hey - sorry to bother you @ssemilla - Any chance that you might know how to set the falue of the property once we get it in this fashion? I am trying to learn reflection here - and I just don't grasp it right now!

Comment: There is `Value.Set()`, I suggest you read https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection but reflection should be your last resort. I often see people coming from dynamic languages not taking advantage of the type system and still solve everything like a hash map.