# Fetch info of multiple struct dynamically in loop

Tags: mongodb, go, go-gin

I need to fetch collection list and each collection's keys from Mongodb and compare those key in loop with struct which has same name as collection name

Struct in dettails.go

```
type Chats struct {
    Id  string
    Value string
}
```

//Controller.go
Fetched collection list from Mongodb

```
names, err := db.CollectionNames()
```

Loop over collection list and fetched each collection's key list
Example collection chats has key Id and Value
Now in the same loop I tried to fetch fields of struct (collection name is similar to struct name)

```
for _, name := range names {
     clKeyList := keylist(name)

     a := &models.name{} // here calling struct dynamically for every iteration but name gives error
     fmt.Println(name)

}
```

Please suggest some solution, working since last two days to resolve.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930910/access-struct-property-by-name

Comment: @Magiq This is not a appropriate answer. I already explained above that I have multiple struct in different models. I run a loop to collection list and on every iteration I have to call relevant struct inside for loop   based on collection name.

Comment: You can define a map that maps from the name to the object you want, e.g., `map[string]interface{}`.