# Converting command line argument to use as struct field

Tags: go, command-line-arguments

I am trying to print a JSON(converted to struct) field particularly which is taken as input from terminal.

```
type foo struct{ 
field1 string
field2 int
}
```

This is struct sample that i created and i want to take "field1" as command-line argument and print it to html body or console by reaching decoded JSON output.

Normally i can print it this way but i couldn't find a way to convert **os.Args[1]** value to field of struct which was already defined.

```
var res *foo
_=json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&res)
fmt.Println(res.field1)
```

In summary, is there a way to convert any string variable to function/method. Thanks a lot in advance

Rev. note: eg.
i will write to terminal:

```
go run main.go "field1"
```

the program will do something like this

```
fmt.Fprintf(writer, "option.field is %v", someFuncThatConcatenatesThisTwo("option."+ os.Args[1]))
```

Btw, There is multiple fields to be called. Predefining could solve for a certain case of course but i want to learn is something else.

Comment: I think you could be helped much better if you really understood what you are trying to do and what exactly you want to get out of it.

It's just not clear to me what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In summary, is there a way to convert any string to function/method.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here. It doesn't make any sense.

---

In general, to populate struct fields using command line args, you could do something like the following.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "os"
)

type Options struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 int64
}

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        log.Fatal("missing two required positional arguments: Field1 and Field2")
    }

    opts := &Options{}
    opts.Field1 = os.Args[1]

    var err error
    opts.Field2, err = strconv.ParseInt(os.Args[2], 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to parse integer value: %v", os.Args[2])
    }

    fmt.Println(opts)
}
```

To make your life a whole lot easier, you could use [`flag`](https://pkg.go.dev/flag) (or [`pflag`](https://github.com/spf13/pflag)) package to declare input arguments as command-line flags.

```golang
import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

type Options struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 int
}

var opts Options

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&opts.Field1, "field1", "", "help message for field1")
    flag.IntVar(&opts.Field2, "field2", 0, "help message for field2")
    flag.Parse()
}

func main() {
   fmt.Println(opts)
}
```

Or, like @Jomaar answered, you could use a helper library like [`go-arg`](https://github.com/alexflint/go-arg) to avoid manually declaring command-line flags. Another alternative is [`go-flags`](https://github.com/jessevdk/go-flags).

---

#### Edit

After further clarification, it appears that you want to selectively write the fields of a struct using a writer and you want to use positional command-line arguments to specify which fields to write.

I think `map` will be a more suitable data structure for storing options in this case since it will allow you to simply refer to fields using their `string` keys.

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    options := map[string]interface{} {
        "field1": "some-value",
        "field2": 1,
    }

    for _, arg := range os.Args[1:] {
        if val, ok := options[arg]; ok {
            fmt.Println(val)
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to continue using structs, you can use the [`reflect`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect) package.

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "reflect"
)

type Options struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 int
}

func main() {
    opts := &Options{Field1: "some-value", Field2: 1}

    for _, arg := range os.Args[1:] {
        fmt.Println(getAttr(opts, arg))
    }
}

// copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66470232/2410641
func getAttr(obj interface{}, fieldName string) (reflect.Value, error) {
    pointToStruct := reflect.ValueOf(obj) // addressable
    curStruct := pointToStruct.Elem()
    if curStruct.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return reflect.Value{}, fmt.Errorf("obj is not a struct")
    }
    curField := curStruct.FieldByName(fieldName) // type: reflect.Value
    if !curField.IsValid() {
        return reflect.Value{}, fmt.Errorf("field not found: %s", fieldName)
    }
    return curField, nil
}
```

Go Playground demo: https://play.golang.org/p/sch53l2bq4O

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't seem related what i want to ask. So I Edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @Alteran Do you want your program to use a writer to print the struct fields you specify via command-line flags?

Comment: Yes but not as a flag. As i understand flags are start with - notation. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Reflection solved it like magic. Now i need to digest . Thanks