# How to set the composite field of a struct field by name in Go?

Tags: go, struct, reflect

I have a struct with one of it's fields being another struct and I would like to access this struct by name (as a parameter). I followed [Using reflect, how do you set the value of a struct field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395076/using-reflect-how-do-you-set-the-value-of-a-struct-field) and it works for basic type but not for composite types.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)


type PntInt struct {
    p *int64
}

type Foo struct {
    X  int64
    Px PntInt
}

func main() {
    foo := Foo{}
    fmt.Println(foo)
    i := int64(8)
    Pi := PntInt{&i}
    reflect.ValueOf(&foo).Elem().FieldByName("X").SetInt(i)
    reflect.ValueOf(&foo).Elem().FieldByName("Px").Set(Pi)
    fmt.Println(foo)
}
```

setting the integer works but trying to set "Px" fails with the error

```
./prog.go:25:52: cannot use Pi (type PntInt) as type reflect.Value in argument to reflect.ValueOf(&foo).Elem().FieldByName("Px").Set
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a `Value`:

```
reflect.ValueOf(&foo).Elem().FieldByName("Px").Set(reflect.ValueOf(Pi))
```

[Here it is running on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/8tzr3ciL_iS)