# get reflect.struct from interface

Tags: go, struct, reflection

hi a have this func for get type of value, but i try this and never can get reflect.struct:

```
type Test struct {
    Code int   
    Name string
}
func main(){
    test := getTest()
    data, err := getBytes(slice...)
    sanitizedFile := bytes.Split(data, []byte("\r\n"))
    err = Unmarshal(sanitizedFile[0], &test)
}
func getTest() interface{} {
    return Test{}
}
```

With this code i don't can get the reflecet.struct from v params in Unmarshall func

```
func Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(v)

    if rv.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        rvElem := rv.Elem()
        
        switch rvElem.Kind() {
        case reflect.Struct:
           // implement me
        }
    }
    return ErrInvalid
}
```

I would like to know if I can somehow find out if an interface is of type struct or access the values ​​of that struct.

Comment: You're passing a pointer to an interface (`*interface{}`), so, I believe, you need *two* `Elem` calls.

Comment: Note that `*interface{}{struct{...}}` is not the same as `interface{}{*struct{...}}`, it's actually quite different. Using pointer-to-interface instead of pointer-to-struct will probably break your unmarshal implementation.

Comment: You can use a loop within which you call `Elem` if the given input can be a mixture of pointers (even multiple) and interfaces: https://play.golang.org/p/a4h1gBR2Xri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the real problem here is illustrated by this quote:

> I would like to know if I can somehow find out if an interface is of type struct or access the values ​​of that struct.

An interface value *isn't* "of type struct".  **Never!**  An interface value can *contain a value whose type is some structure*, but it *is not* a value of that type.  It just *contains* one.  This is similar to the way that a box<sup>1</sup> you get from Amazon can *contain* a corkscrew, but the box *is not* a corkscrew, ever.

Given a non-nil value of type `interface I` for some interface type `I`, you know that you have a value that implements the methods of `I`.  Since `{}` is the empty set of methods, all types implement it, so given a (still non-nil) value of type `interface{}`, you have a value that implements no methods.  That's not at all useful by itself: it means you can invoke no methods, which means you can't do anything method-like.

But just because you can't do anything method-y doesn't mean you can't do anything *at all*.  Any interface value, regardless of the interface type, can have a type-assertion used on it:

```
iv := somethingThatReturnsAnInterface()
cv := iv.(struct S) // assert that iv contains a `struct S`
```

If `iv` does in fact contain a `struct S` value—if that's what's inside the box once you open it—then this type-assertion *doesn't* panic, and `cv` winds up with the concrete value of type `struct S`.  If panic is undesirable, we can use the `cv, ok := iv.(struct S)` form, or a type switch.  All of these—including the version that panics—work by *checking the type of the value inside the interface*.

What this—or, more precisely, the way the Go language is defined—tells us is that the `interface` "box" really holds two things:

- a concrete type, and
- a concrete value.

Well, that is, unless it holds a <nil, nil> pair, in which case `iv == nil` is true.  Note that the `iv == nil` test actually tests *both parts*.

If Go had a syntax for this, we could write something like `iv.type` and `iv.value` to get at the two separate parts.  But we can't do that.  We have to use type assertions, type-switch, or `reflect`.  So, going back to this:

> I would like to know if I can somehow find out if an interface is of type struct

we can see that the question itself is just a little malformed.  We don't want to know if an interface value *has* this type.  We want to know if a non-nil interface's *held value* is *of* this type, as if we could inspect `iv.type` and `iv.value` directly.

If you have a limited set of possible types, you can use the type-switch construct, and enumerate all your allowed possiblities:

```
switch cv := iv.(type) {
case struct S:
    // work with cv, which is a struct S
case *struct S:
    // work with cv, which is a *struct S
// add more cases as appropriate
}
```

If you need more generality, instead of doing the above, we end up using the `reflect` package:

```
tv := reflect.TypeOf(iv)
```

or:

```
vv := reflect.ValueOf(iv)
```

The latter is actually the more useful form, since `vv` captures both the `iv.type` pseudo-field *and* the `iv.value` pseudo-field.

As [mkopriva notes in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69327690/get-reflect-struct-from-interface#comment122535462_69327690), `test`, in your sample code, has type `interface{}`, so `&test` has type `*interface{}`.  In most cases this is not a good idea: you just want to pass the `interface{}` value directly.

To allow the called function to *set* the object to a *new value*, you will want to pass a pointer to the object as the interface value.  You do not want to pass a pointer to the interface while having the interface hold the struct "in the box" as it were.  You need a `reflect.Value` on which you can invoke `Set()`, and to get one, you will need to follow an `elem` on the `reflect.Value` that is a pointer to the struct (not one that is a pointer to the interface).

There's a more complete example [here on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/n0wJxImKclh).

---

<sup>1</sup>This is partly an allusion to "boxed values" in certain other programming languages (see [What is boxing and unboxing and what are the trade offs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13055/1256452)), but partly literal.  Don't mistake Go's interfaces for Java's boxed values, though: they are not the same at all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you need is type assertion?

t, ok := v.(myStruct)

https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

In any case this code prints "struct":

```
    type tt struct {}

    var x tt
    var z interface{}
    z = x
    v := reflect.ValueOf(z).Kind()
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", v)
```

And see this for setting the value of a struct field using reflection:

[Using reflect, how do you set the value of a struct field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395076/using-reflect-how-do-you-set-the-value-of-a-struct-field)